# black screen during shutdown

Tags: gnome, shutdown

Good morning.
I'm testing the 13.04 64bit with Gnome-shell 3.6.3.1.
It happens randomly after choosing shutdown of the machine, I receive a black screen "stuck" (no splash screen, no messages). Obviously the machine does not turn off and get stuck in that phase until I restart it manually.
I looked at the syslog and I found this:

```
Apr 12 22:49:20 banco-dt colord: device removed: xrandr-Philips Consumer Electronics Company-Philips 170C- BZ  226700
Apr 12 22:49:20 banco-dt colord: Profile removed: icc-e5133a63b0b32ba08084148e2c179a10
Apr 12 22:49:20 banco-dt gnome-session[1559]: CRITICAL: gsm_manager_set_phase: assertion `GSM_IS_MANAGER (manager)' failed
Apr 12 22:49:20 banco-dt gnome-session[1559]: Gtk-CRITICAL: gtk_main_quit: assertion `main_loops != NULL' failed
```

From the first line, it seems to make sense to have no signal in the monitor. The two CRITICAL following errors seem to be the cause of the stuck.
Any idea?

P.S.
Sorry for my poor english

bancaldo.

Comment: ubuntu 12.10 kernel 3.5.0.27 has no problem.

Comment: change the string GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="reboot=bios" in /etc/default/grub solved the problem. Quiet and splash flags were removed for debugging.